# Internal Server Error on Django Deploy

Tags: python, django, apache, django-admin, deployment

Im getting 500 internal server error everytime I try access my admin or login page. There's nothing in my error.log

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you enable error reporting via email? http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/error-reporting/ If so, what's the info in the emails?

Comment: Is your db running? Post output.

Comment: The output is just apache's default 500 error page, with no traceback. My db is sqlite3 and was generated on the server with syncdb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My DEBUG was set True. I found the error on my apache_log. The problem was that my sqlite3 database was a read only file.

Answer (score 3):

Set DEBUG = True so that you can see the Django traceback